# Can't connect ubuntu hyper-v using all my monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, hyper-v

I have Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS VM on my windows 10 with enhanced mode enabled.
I'm using GTX 1660 and the machine work perfectly fine when i'm connecting it on any resolution and even on full mode.
But when I try to use "All my monitors" I get one disconnect after I enter my credentials and on the second time I get just black screen on both screens.
If i'll try to close the hyper-v window and open it again choosing a different resolution, i'll get weird version of desktop without the dock.

When I revert the VM i can connect using all monitors but once i'll reboot the problem will happen again

Any suggestions ?